# simple fb connect enter custom user field in field group for new users

Tags: 7, users, entities, social-network

I need a help with an issue that I am facing in the module.

So, on my registration page I have some extra fields like:

- Country
- Real name (different from username)

Country and real name value is in field group and the name is as following

Name : `field_primary_contact[und][0][field_contact_name][und][0][value]`
(taxonomy term) Country : `field_primary_contact[und][0][field_contact_country][und]`

in my hook_simple_fb_connect_registration  I set the following value

example

```
$drupal_user->field_primary_contact[und][0][field_contact_name][und][0][value] = "fb hook testing";

$drupal_user->field_primary_contact[und][0][field_contact_country][und] = 40;
```

It doesn't work. Do we need to do anything different for field groups?